# Why is this the possible Taylor series???

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I am looking at an exercise at which it is asked to find the Taylor series of $f(x)=\log(1+x)$, $\xi=0, x \in (-1,1)$

$$f'(x)=(1+x)^{-1}$$
$$f''(x)=-1 \cdot (1+x)^{-2}$$
$$f'''(x)=2 \cdot (1+x)^{-3}$$
$$f^{(4)}(x)=-6 \cdot (1+x)^{-4}$$

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)= \frac{(-1)^{n-1} (n-1)!}{(1+x)^n}$$

According to my notes, the possible Taylor series is:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} (n-1)!}{(1+x)^n}$$

But,why is it like that?

Isn't the formula for the Taylor series: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!} (x-\xi)^n$$
? Or am I wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your notes apparently have an error.
The series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1} (n-1)!}{(1+x)^n}
$$
is first of all not a Taylor series, and second of all, converges nowhere by the ratio test:
$$
\left| \frac{(-1)^{n} n!}{(1+x)^{n+1}}
\cdot
\frac{(1+x)^n}{(-1)^{n-1} (n-1)!} \right|
=
\left| \frac{-n}{1+x} \right|  \to \infty.
$$

> Isn't the formula for the Taylor series: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!} (x-\xi)^n$$
>   ? Or am I wrong??

Almost; replace $(n+1)!$ with $n!$ and your formula is right.
The correct Taylor series is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(\xi)}{n!} (x-\xi)^n
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty 
\frac{(-1)^{n-1} (n-1)!}{(1 + 0)^n} \frac{x^n}{n!}
= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} x^n.
$$
(the $n = 0$ term is $0$).

Comment: Yes, I also found this Taylor series... Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @evinda You're welcome!

Comment: And ,then to verify that it is actually like that,do we have to do the following?

$$|R_{n,0}(x, \zeta)|=\frac{|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)(1+\zeta)^n} \leq \frac{|x|^{n+1}}{n+1} \to 0$$

Comment: @evinda "it is actually like that"?  To calculate the Taylor series itself, you merely need to calculate all the derivatives.  But if you want to check *where* it converges, generally ratio test is easier than checking the Lagrange remainder.